# Is the neo4j documentation inconsistent regarding embedding parameter?

Tags: neo4j

In this tutorial, it has the following example:
https://neo4j.com/developer/graph-data-science/applied-graph-embeddings/
where 'embeddingSize' is used for specify the vector length of the embedding.

```
CALL gds.alpha.node2vec.stream({
  nodeProjection: "Place",
  relationshipProjection: {
    eroad: {
      type: "EROAD",
      orientation: "UNDIRECTED"
    }
  },
  embeddingSize: 10,
  iterations: 10,
  walkLength: 10
})
YIELD nodeId, embedding
RETURN gds.util.asNode(nodeId).name AS place, embedding
LIMIT 5;
```

However, in the signature of the node2vec documentation, it use 'embeddingDimension', instead of 'embeddingSize'. Are the same thing? Or Either the documentation of the tutorial is outdated? See below for 'embeddingDimension':
https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/node2vec/#alpha-algorithms-embeddings-node2vec

Comment: embeddingDimension is NEW, embeddingSize is OLD. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Graph embeddings were introduced in version 1.3 and the tutorial you found is for that version and it uses embeddingSize.  Then 2nd link you found is the recent documentation for node2Vec and it is meant for >= 1.4 version.  Look at the header of your 2nd link and you will see below

```
Neo4j Graph Data Science >
The Neo4j Graph Data Science Library Manual v1.5  >
Algorithms  >
Node embeddings  >
Node2Vec
```

Neo4j documentations are not up-to-date so if you are really into code, you can look at the github here: https://github.com/neo4j/graph-data-science.  It is changing at speed of light!